# postgresql lock user without activity

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgagent

I have to lock users who don t work  in the previous three months.
I'm very newbie!
 I looked at the documentation and I do nt think I can do this by configuration.
(Is it true?) 
So I have to develop a daily procedure ( with pgagent?) ,make a query and then lock users but  I cant find a system table that has this information.
Could you help me?
Thanks a lot
Gian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, the time of the last login is not recorded in the database, only in the log file (if logging is suitably configured).

I think you won't be able to implement this without the aid of the application that uses PostgreSQL. I can think of two possibilities:

- Create a table where your application records the last login time. Your periodic job can then use that table to decide if it should lock a user.
- Create a function like this:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expire_me() RETURNS void
     LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
     SET search_path = 'pg_catalog' AS
  $$BEGIN
     EXECUTE 'ALTER ROLE ' || session_user || ' VALID UNTIL ''' ||
             (current_timestamp + INTERVAL '3 months') || '''';
  END;$$;
  ```

  The application then calls the function immediately after a user logs in. If the next login is more than three months later, the user will be locked.

Unfortunately there is no such thing as a “login trigger” is PostgreSQL, that would make this much simpler.

Comment: thanks Laurenz but  I should do this for the security of the database regardless of the applications...
perhaps I can make authenticate users with something like PAM (... but I dont know it's a win machine)..  Cheers Gian

Comment: You are right; in that case a solution outside the database is preferrable.

Comment: mmm...PAM I think  is not available on win ... Does anyone have experience of authentication systems on windows that can be configured with rules like that??